# TypeError when trying to sort long list

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of items which can be sorted, they are of the form:

```
example_files = ['LJ028-0299.txt', 'LJ029-0000.txt', 'LJ001-3214.txt']
```

where sorted returns

```
['LJ001-3214.txt', 'LJ028-0299.txt', 'LJ029-0000.txt']
```

However, I have a folder of ~13,000 files and need them sorted in a list. I have appended them to a list:

```
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    files.append(files)
```

But when doing `sorted(files)` I get a TypeError:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'str'
```

I suspect this is because the output of `files` includes this at the end:

```
'LJ010-0151.txt', 'LJ027-0128.txt', [...]]
```

I don't necessarily need to use a list, I just need to be able to iterate over the files and use the information inside each as input to a class. I thought that this method would be the easiest way, as looping over them normally doesn't sort them for whatever reason.

Comment: you've got some items of type `list` in your list, sorting needs all the same type, in this case, `str`.

Comment: I know; I posted what I thought was the list it was referring to (````[...]````) and I'm not sure how to get rid of this because it is just a list with filenames added to it; there are no actual lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be shadowing your variable.

> for root, subdirs, **files** in os.walk(rootdir):
>       **files**.append(**files**)

Have you tried:

```
file_list = []
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
     file_list.append(files)
# access your list here
```

Or shorter one:
`file_list = [files for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir)]`

Answer (score 0):

You might have **Non-Comparable Data Types** in you list. You must not and cannot use "sort" on data types that are different from each other.

In your case you have a list in a list, e.g. below:

data = ['a', 'b', 'd', ['1', '2']]
print(sorted(data))

Above **sorted** data will definitely raise "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'str'"

do some checking on your files using "isinstance(data, list)" and if return True extend instead of append.

example of code below:
rootdir.txt contains:
'a'
['1', '2']

```
list_text = []    
with open ('rootdir.txt', 'r') as files:
    for text in file:
        if isinstance(text, list):
            list_text.extend(text)
        else
            list_text.append(text)
```

I just noticed that you used 'files' to append 'files'. Declare another empty list then append files there ***might actually resolve*** your problem.

```
data_in_files = []
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    data_in_files.append(files)
```